# Client Side MVC Validation not firing on mouse(Tab) out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

Am trying to have client side validation using Data Annotations and  JQUERY for my web page.

I have set up my property in model

```
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

And i set up Scripts using Bundle.config which is rendered in my page as below

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

and in my web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

My HTML is renderd as expected

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name" data-val-required="The Name field is required." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line">
```

On click of Submit the Client side validation is firing as Expected.

**My problem is Why it is not firing on mouse or Tab out ??**

Am i missing something or doing wrong ?? I searched and tried everything but still validation not works on mouse or Tab out.

Even i tried creating a new sample with just one property but still i cant make it work. Any Help would be appreciated

Thanks

---Updated with view code sample ---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </div>

....

sample code may be brackets missing
```

Comment: can you please provide your razor code. you have done all well. Only need to check you Razor code...Its firing but you have not setup css/ or @html.Validationfor .

Comment: @Janty updated with view code. Am having html.Validationfor and it shows up correctly on button click but not on mouse out ?

Comment: Well. Have you check @html.beginform tag?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("AgencyRegistrationPrincipales", "AgencyRegistration", FormMethod.Post))
{  }

Comment: @Janty yes am having the HTML Form as well bt still not firing up :( updated code

Comment: Please try explicitely with FormMethod.Post once

Comment: @Janty tried !!  using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "nameForm"}))

Comment: @Peru Did you debug the script that is called on the client side? Try adding a breakpoint using Firebug, maybe on `$(document).ready()`, and check if the `$.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings.onfocusout` property is `true`. See this for how it works: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: does it fire, when you click on some free space (causing a blur without the tab key)?

Comment: You might want to check my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448764/unobtrusive-validation-with-data-val-requiredsubmit-does-break-tab-sequence, maybe it is in any way related?